# C++: can I force my programmers to define copy constructor for each class?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

can I force my programmers to define copy constructor for each class that inherits from base class. The base class can be instantiated.

I mean if I have

```
class A {
public
  A(const A&);
};

class B : public A {
public
  B(const B&); // I want to force my programmers to write this line, any idea????
};
```

Comment: Why would you want to force this? A compiler provided copy constructor will use the user defined copy constructor for the base class in any case.

Comment: Use the QA tools at your disposal to check for this when checking code in?

Comment: This requirement is wrong. You want to avoid manual copy constructors, not enforce them.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the answer is in [CRTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern).

The closest solution I can figure out right now is a pseudo base and a CRTP with a private abstract copy_construct function to remind the programmers.

```
template <class Derived>
class Base {
private:
    virtual void copy_construct(const Derived& d) = 0;

      //btw; unfortunately this isn't possible: 
      //virtual Derived(const Derived& b) = 0;
};

class PseudoBase : public Base<PseudoBase>
{
public:
    PseudoBase() {};
    PseudoBase(const PseudoBase& pd) 
    { 
        copy_construct(pd); 
    }

private:       
    void copy_construct(const PseudoBase& rhs) 
    {
        //copy code
    }
};

class Derived : public Base<Derived>
{
  //Programmer forgot about copy constructing    

};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    PseudoBase pb0;
    PseudoBase pb1 = pb0;

    Derived d0;
    Derived d1 = d0;

    return 0;
}
```

The build will fail:

```
1>d:\source\test\test\test\test.cpp(42): error C2259: 'Derived' : cannot instantiate abstract class
1>          due to following members:
1>          'void Base<Derived>::copy_construct(const Derived &)' : is abstract
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Derived=Derived
1>          ]
1>          d:\source\test\test\test\test.cpp(9) : see declaration of 'Base<Derived>::copy_construct'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Derived=Derived
1>          ]
```

Comment: Hi Hubert, nice idea, but 1. here we cant force the "grandson" of Base to create the CTOR. 2. isnt is much simpler to make the base class copy CTOR protected?

Comment: You have a point. But it's the closest answer I could think off. But I don't see what a protected copy constructor would do for you.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I believe there is a way to *sort of* do this, following Hubert's answer. You can define an abstract class that forces all subclasses to implement some copy method using a template:

```
template <class X>
class IsCopyable{
protected:
    virtual void copy(const X&) = 0
};
```

Then you leverage the CRTP like so:

```
template <class Y>
class AbstractClass : public IsCopyable<Y>{
    ...
};
```

Say we inherit from AbstractClass using ConcreteClass.h:

```
class ConcreteClass : public AbstractClass<ConcreteClass>{
private:
    virtual void copy(const ConcreteClass&) override; // from IsCopyable abstract class
public:
    ConcreteClass();
    ConcreteClass(const ConcreteClass&);
};
```

In ConcreteClass.cpp:

```
#include "ConcreteClass.h"

void copy(const ConcreteClass& copyme){ // ConcreteClass is forced to implement this
    ...
}

ConcreteClass(const ConcreteClass& copyme){ // unfortunately, it's not forced to implement this
    copy(copyme);
}
```

It doesn't really force classes inheriting from IsCopyable to include the copy constructor itself, but I think it's the next best thing. Any thoughts/improvements?

Answer (score -5):

I strongly feel that the bugs and runtime crashes will force your developers to write that piece of line

Comment: What bugs? What runtime crashes? How is this relevant? The Q asks to force derived classes to provide user defined copy constructor *before* facing bugs.

Comment: @Als: If you have a pointer in the class and try to free the memory in the destructor. If your programmer forgets to write a copy constructor then it leads to a crash

Comment: Rule of Three is not a standard mandated rule.So it doesn't enforce anything.

Comment: Yes, this is what I mean, I don't want to debug the bugs, but rather force the declaration of copy construction of each class that inherits A.

Comment: @bochaltura: Manually writing copy ctors can be **more** error prone than letting the compuiler synthesize one.